# Question about research procedure

Tags: research-process, mathematics, reading

It is a well known fact that to be a good researcher, one needs to read a fair amount of technical papers. I am primarily interested in mathematical sciences. My questions are the following:

1. How do professional researchers keep track of the papers they read?
   Do they print out the papers and keep them in a box? Or do they just take notes of names of the papers for future reference?
2. Do people finish a particular paper in a single go or do they just leave it if they dont get it initially and keep coming back in the future with a more mature understanding?
3. Is it advisable to put a target in front of me to read a certain number of papers say, in a month? If yes how do you systematically manage your time to read papers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's 4 close-votes on this question right now. It's hard to know exactly why, but asking multiple questions in one post can often lead to close votes with the "needs more focus" reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not much of an idea what others do, but I tell you what I do. I have a list of maybe 15 journals that are likely to have stuff that is relevant to me, and I run through all their issues regularly and have a quick look at all papers that interest me. I have a big file in which I write 1-3 lines (really just keywords) about all these papers. Most important is that I do it so that I can later find the paper in the file with the right keyword(s), and then am able to find it on the web from the information given in my file (of course this assumes that I have web access to the paper when I need it, which to some extent depends on the subscriptions of my institution). Occasionally I'm interested enough to read (and/or save) a whole paper, but in most cases I just try to roughly get what is done there, potentially new interesting ideas etc. I'm to some extent spontaneous regarding how deeply I go into a paper. Then later I sometimes go back and spend more time on one of these papers if for some reason it becomes more relevant to me. I also add papers in other journals or on arxiv and the like if I become aware of them, for example by following references.

Unfortunately all this takes a huge amount of time and I have become more selective (I had more journals at some point in the past, and I also know some people look up arxiv every day which is surely not wrong but I don't have the time to do that) and also on average more superficial when reading. I take some advantage from having done this now for over 20 years, and having some good training in extracting something of interest from papers in very short time. I should maybe also add that I am a statistician, and although we do some proper mathematics, many statistics papers are easier to grasp without going all too deep into technicalities, proof details etc.